# How can you find the beginning of a week for a given date in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

How can I find the beginning week of any given date in Netezza? 
For instance 2017-10-17, the beginning date would be Monday 2017-10-16.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the built-in week definition, then this should work:

```
date_trunc('week', <given date>)
```

Postgres, at least, starts weeks on Monday -- becaues it follows ISO 8601 standards.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this query can help you. Greetings

```
SELECT 'Monday ' || (CAST('2017-10-17' AS DATE) - CAST((Select extract('ISODOW' from '2017-10-17'::date))-1 || 'days' AS INTERVAL))::date respuesta;
```